# About insert identity column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I need to merge some data (include identity column) from other server to my server without interrupting my service running. I export the data from the other server and insert into to my server like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content ON

... insert command ...

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_content OFF
```

However, if I set the `IDENTITY_INSERT` on, other applications inserting data into the database without identity column will get an error

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table '....' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON

How can I insert identity column without interrupting other applications?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Other sessions won't suddenly start getting that error message in the circumstances you describe. This is a session option not a table property.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, you're right. Sorry i haven't tested it. I just imaging it will happen like that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `SqlTransaction` when performing the bulk insert. Yes your table will be locked for some time but atleast you'll guarantee data integrity.